# Swift: NSStatusItem remains highlighted after right-click

Tags: swift, action, appdelegate, nsmenu, nsstatusitem

I created a `NSStatusBarItem` and popUp a (programmatically generated) `NSMenu` on right click:

```
let statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: -1)
statusBarItem.action = #selector(AppDelegate.statusBarItemAction(sender:))

let menu = NSMenu()
var menuItem = NSMenuItem()
menuItem.action = #selector(AppDelegate.customItemAction)
menu.addItem(menuItem)

func statusBarItemAction(sender: NSStatusItem) {
    let mouseEvent = NSEvent.pressedMouseButtons()
    if mouseEvent == 2 {
        // right click
        lxStatusBarItem.popUpMenu(menu)
    }
}

func customItemAction() {
    // do something
}
```

Everything works fine, except that the `statusBarItem` remains highlighted after `customItemAction` is called:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting `statusItem.button?.isHighlighted = false` helped with removing the highlight. In your case, this would look like this:

```
func customItemAction() {
    // do something
    statusBarItem.button?.isHighlighted = false
    ...
}
```

Comment: This does remove the highlight but if you open a NSWindow you still have to click it once before it becomes key, despite makeKeyAndOrderFront.

Comment: @John is there a way around having to click the NSWindow to make it key?  I have tried a number of ways (to include makeKeyAndOrderFront) and I am unable to make it work - including simulating a left click on the window to make it key.

Comment: @MikeManzo I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: @John @MikeManzo I encountered the same issue. Setting `sendAction` to only work with mouse up events worked as a workaround for me.